# Calculating and writing values in a Javascript dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html-table, sas

I want to calculate the values of T1 and T2 in each row of the dynamic table based on the values in the other cells (e.g. di and br). These values as a whole will be sent as macro variables to be treated in SAS program. In this case I have the choice of either inputting or calculating the values of T1 and T2. I am a new user of Javascript. The code that I made is as below. No matter how I tried I couldn't get the values of T1 and T2 written back in the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function addRow(dataTable){
    var table=document.getElementById('dataTable');
    var rowCount=table.rows.length;
    var rowCount1=table.rows.length-1;
    var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var cell01=row.insertCell(-1);var element01=document.createElement("input");element01.type="checkbox";element01.name="chkbox[]";cell01.appendChild(element01);
    var cell02=row.insertCell(-1);var element02=document.createElement("text");element02.name="nr"; cell02.innerHTML=rowCount1+1;
    var cell04=row.insertCell(-1);var element04=document.createElement("input");element04.type="text"; element04.name="di"; element04.id="di"; cell04.appendChild(element04);
    var cell05=row.insertCell(-1);var element05=document.createElement("input");element05.type="text"; element05.name="br"; element04.id="br"; cell05.appendChild(element05);
    var cell07=row.insertCell(-1);var element07=document.createElement("input");element07.type="text";element07.value="CRN"; element07.name="kurve"; element07.id="kurve"; cell07.appendChild(element07);
    var cell27=row.insertCell(-1);var element27=document.createElement("input");element27.type="button";element27.value="send"; element27.onclick="Calculate()"; cell27.appendChild(element27);
    var cell10=row.insertCell(-1);var element10=document.createElement("input");element10.type="text"; element10.name="T1"; element10.id="T1"; element10.style.height='16px'; cell10.appendChild(element10);
    var cell11=row.insertCell(-1);var element11=document.createElement("input");element11.type="text"; element11.name="T2"; element11.id="T2"; cell11.appendChild(element11);
}
function deleteRow(dataTable){
    var table=document.getElementById(dataTable);
    var rowCount=table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
        var row=table.rows[i];
        var chkbox=row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null!=chkbox&&true==chkbox.checked){
            table.deleteRow(i);rowCount--;i--;
        }
    }
}
function Calculate() {
    var T1V = 0;
    var di = table.getElementsById('di').innerHTML;
    var br = table.getElementsById('br').innerHTML;
    var T1V =(100+br/di)*1.1  ;
    document.getElementById('T1').value=T1V;
}             
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="add row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">
<input type="button" value="remove row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')"> 
<table id="dataTable">
   <thead>
       <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;"> &nbsp </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">nr.</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Di</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Br</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Kurve</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;"> &nbsp </th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">T1</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">T2</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unsure what your expected outcome is. Is it the table generating that isn't working or the calculation? I've created [this testbed](http://jsfiddle.net/ko4vgudu/) for your code (and tidied it up a little).

Comment: Thanks a lot! My goal is that with input di, br and a selected kurve on a list (I still need to make a list), I expect to have the calculated T1 and T2 directly shown on the input places. The cells T1 and T2 are set to be "input" because I can also sometimes change the values manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/ko4vgudu/6/

You need to give the elements in the table unique id's, after that you can make calculations, and use the results to fill in the matching cells.

```
function Calculate(el) {
    var row_id = el.id;
    var row_split1 = row_id.split('_')[1];
    di = document.getElementById('di_'+row_split1).value;
    br = document.getElementById('br_'+row_split1).value;
    T1V = (100 + br / di) * 1.1;
    document.getElementById('T1_'+row_split1).value = T1V;
    T2V = (100 + br*1.1 / di) / 1.1;
    document.getElementById('T2_'+row_split1).value = T2V;
};
```